# How to use toastify.js installed by npm? I get "Failed to resolve module specifier"

Tags: javascript, npm, libraries, react-toastify

Im trying to use Toastify-js, a library for toast type messages, installing it using npm.
In the documentation, after running the installing comand it says:

> -Import toastify-js into your module to start using it.
> import Toastify from 'toastify-js'

but when i inlude that import line in my code i get this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "toastify-js".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I think theres probably something im not understanding... where should i put that line? or what im doing wrong. Is the documentation assuming something about using npm-installed libraries that I don't know about, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late for answering but I just found out about it myself right now. In order to use toastify-js by installing through npm in Laravel blade files firstly we must compile a JavaScript file which consists of importing Toastify.

Firstly of course, install the toastify-js.

```
npm install --save toastify-js
```

And in a JavaScript file import the Toastify and CSS of it. For me, I just went with the default app.js

resources/js/app.js

```
import Toastify from 'toastify-js'
import "toastify-js/src/toastify.css"

window.Toastify = Toastify;
```

And after that we must compile the "app.js" file in vite.config.js.

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

After the compilation, we can just link the app.js file through the vite blade directive in our blade file. You can just put the directive before the closing body tag or anywhere you like if you want to.

```
 @vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

And then anywhere in your blade files you can just write the script to show the toast.

```
<script type="module">
        Toastify({
            text: "Hello, I am toasted!!",
            duration: 3000,
            destination: "",
            newWindow: true,
            close: true,
            gravity: "bottom", // `top` or `bottom`
            position: "right", // `left`, `center` or `right`
            stopOnFocus: true, // Prevents dismissing of toast on hover
            style: {
                background: "linear-gradient(to right, #00b09b, #96c93d)",
            },
            onClick: function() {} // Callback after click
        }).showToast();
    </script>
```

And also makes sure that the script tag has the type of "module". Or else, the toast will not show up.

I hope you can show toast the same way by following those steps. Please let me know if I have anything that I should know to fix or to improve this method.

Also, in order to know how to customize your toast better, make sure to read the toastify-js docs.
https://github.com/apvarun/toastify-js/blob/master/README.md